# uppercase first character in a variable in batch file for windows

Tags: batch-file

I want to uppercase just the first character in my string with the windows batch file.

```
set foo="bar"

//uppercase first character

echo %foo%;
```

Expected Output: Bar

Comment: I don't even know if there *is* an uppercase for `"`

Comment: @Stephan: I agree **`;)`** The expected output would be `"bar";;`. Perhaps the OP wants to uppercase the _second_ character _AND_ to remove the first and the two last characters, and remove the last `;` (and also to eliminate the "Command not found error" message from the `//uppercase first character` line)...

Comment: @Aacini LOL. Close as "unclear" then?

Comment: @Stephan : Be kind to the Java programmers. We can't expect them to be able to count. We'll even overlook the missing attempt, seeing as Nishant has earned his stripes - albeit in a strange field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "foo=bar"
SET foo
:: get first character
SET "c1=%foo:~0,1%"
:: make it uppercase. Note that the string-substitution is case-insensitive on the 
:: "from" string, but replaces literally.
:: Obviously, A B C should be the full alphabet, which I assign as a user-defined environment string
:: bizarrely called "alphabet"
FOR %%s IN (A B C) DO CALL SET "c1=%%c1:%%s=%%s%%"
SET "foo=%c1%%foo:~1%"
SET foo
GOTO :EOF
```

Assigning quoted strings to variables make the variables hard to combine logically. Inserting quotes as needed is far simpler.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

The magic is in the line

```
FOR %%s IN (A B C) DO CALL SET "c1=%%c1:%%s=%%s%%"
```

which will attempt to execute "substitute literal `%%s` for each `%%s` (case-insensitive) found in the string `c1`. In this case, I chose to invoke the `call` of the `set` in a sub-shell to avoid the complexities of the `delayed expansion` saga.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Magoo answer, I have written a simple logical script to achieve the same.

```
 @echo off & SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET STR=bar
:: Taking the rest of the string as it is as we don't need to change that.
    set "restStr=%STR:~1,20%"
:: Taking the first character of the string and doing it to upper case.
    set upper=
    set "str=%STR:~0,1%"
    for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%I in ('tree "\%str%"') do if not defined upper set "upper=%%~I"
    set "upper=%upper:~3%"
:: Printing the result by concating both of them.
    echo %upper%%restStr%
    pause
```

Output is : **Bar**